# facebook comments box in ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Is there any library to implement facebook comments box into an iOS app? I don't want to use comments plugin in uiwebview since I need to create/modify/destroy comments based on facebook object id. I already set up facebook single signon using facebook sdk for iOS. I know how to implement (and already have) this feature using facebook graph api. I was just wondering if something ready to use with ui and everything else is available.